# lifting (not just homotopies!) theorems for fibrations?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Is there an analogue of the lifting theorem for covering spaces in the situation of fibrations?

In particular, given a fibration $f : E\rightarrow S$ and an automorphism $\sigma\in Aut(S)$, can you lift $\sigma$ to an automorphism of $E$ making the obvious square commute? (This is a bit stronger than a fiber-product/pullback, since here we require that both ``vertical'' maps are given by $f$) If not, is there a way to describe the obstruction in the same way as the fundamental group presents an obstruction for the lifting theorem for covering maps?

Even more in particular, I'm thinking of the case where $E$ is a (family of) elliptic curve(s), though I wouldn't think that matters...

Comment: Fibrations are required to have the homotopy lifting property by definition, but it in no way needs to be unique.

Comment: Right certainly one would not expect any lift to be unique, but I'm not only asking for lifting homotopies, but lifts of general maps.